# What is the best way to handle an Outbound Message with Ruby on Rails?

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have an outbound message being set into a Ruby on Rails Application. What is the best way to handle an incoming message? I have read a few posts that suggest using a gem such as Savon to handle the SOAP message. I currently have my application set up to use the restforce gem to do interactions with the SF API.